# Error when installing older version of cordova

Tags: cordova, npm, phonegap

Hi i'm trying to install an older version of cordova. The version i want is 2.2.0 so what i did was:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@2.2.0
```

during installation, i got an error involving './bin/notice'. here is the full output

```
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.7.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.1.5: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.1.14: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\roses\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\roses\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova

> cordova@2.2.0 install C:\Users\roses\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
> ./bin/notice

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cordova@2.2.0 install: `./bin/notice`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cordova@2.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\roses\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-14T07_37_29_411Z-debug.log
```

Please help me. i need to use the older version of cordova immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are trying to add has either been deprecated or never existed. Check out available versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-lib) (then click versions tab)